# No error no execution while writing Wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

The following is my php code for the plugin:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Grid Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fixtures.js"></script>
    <script src="js/gridList.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.gridList.js"></script>
    <script src="js/load.js"></script>
</head>

<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Testingplugin
Plugin URI: http://localhost
Description: Trying plugin for the first time.
Version: 1.0
Author: AIMS
Author URI: http://localhost
License: A "Slug" license name e.g. GPL2
*/
// Exampe is from the https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GAwPa4fP90c
add_action('admin_menu', 'myfirstpluginactions');

function myfirstpluginactions(){
    add_options_page('Title_of_the_plugin','name_of_submenu','manage_options', __FILE__,'display_menu_page');
}

function display_menu_page(){
        ?>



    <body>
    <div class="header">
        <a href="#remove-row" class="button remove-row">-</a>
        <a href="#add-row" class="button add-row">+</a>
        <p>
            <a class="github-button" href="https://github.com/hootsuite/grid" data-style="mega" data-count-href="/hootsuite/grid/stargazers" data-count-api="/repos/hootsuite/grid#stargazers_count" data-count-aria-label="# stargazers on GitHub" aria-label="Star hootsuite/grid on GitHub">GitHub</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <ul id="grid" class="grid">
            <li class="position-highlight">
                <div class="inner"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script async defer id="github-bjs" src="https://buttons.github.io/buttons.js"></script>


    <?php
}
```

I am using the [Hootsuite Grid](https://github.com/hootsuite/grid) Repository for displaying the dragable elements using the plugin.
The problem is I could not get the output and nor I am getting any error. My guess is the problem with the inclusion of the js.

I have included all the js in the js folder of my plugin. Kindly, let me know what might be the cause and what I can do to improve the code.

Here is the output that I get on the screen:

[image: output image]

And this is what I was expecting:

[image: expected image]

Comment: Are all js files definitely getting included?

Comment: @ProEvilz I am a bit confused regarding that. I could not see any error. That means everything might be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add the JS using the wp_enqueue_script() functions, then use plugins_url() to get the path to the JS files.

Something along the lines of added to you plugin initial function:

`wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script-new-name-for-each-script', plugins_url( 'js/fixtures.js', FILE ), array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-core' ), time(), true );`

Also

`wp_enqueue_style( plugins_url( 'css/style.css', FILE ) );` for your CSS.

Do the above for each one of your JS files in the plugin folder. Removing the header html you have added, and no need to the jquery stuff as WP will add it as a requirement.

Your function would become:

```
function myfirstpluginactions(){
    add_options_page('Title_of_the_plugin','name_of_submenu','manage_options', __FILE__,'display_menu_page');

wp_enqueue_style( plugins_url( 'css/style.css', FILE ) );
//Add this for each of your JS scripts
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script-new-name-for-each-script', plugins_url( 'js/fixtures.js', FILE ), array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-core' ), time(), true );

}
```

or another way would be to wrap your current code with PHP to get the right paths to the JS e.g change

```
<script src="js/fixtures.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="<?php echo plugins_url( 'js/fixtures.js', FILE); ?>"></script>
```

Comment: Where exactly I need to add that? Please tell me if there is any examplethat you can refer or suggest correction to my code please.

Comment: Please add some details to your answer, else you might get downvoted.

Comment: you want to add it to your myfirstpluginactions() function ... something along the lines of 'wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script-new-name-for-each-script', plugins_url( 'js/fixtures.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-core' ), time(), true );' Also 'wp_enqueue_style( plugins_url( 'css/style.css', __FILE__ ) );' for your CSS. Do the above for each one of your JS files in the plugin folder. Removing the header html you have added, and no need to the jquery stuff as WP will add it as a requirement.

Comment: Please add it to your answer if possible.

Comment: Do I need to repeat this line for all the js files of my code: `wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script-new-name-for-each-script', plugins_url( 'js/fixtures.js', FILE ), array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-core' ), time(), true );`?

Comment: Yes, changing the 'custom-script-new-name-for-each-script' bit to a new name and edit plugins_url( 'js/fixtures.js', FILE ) to the next file you need.

Comment: Added a more detailed example above now.

Comment: Added another way to fix the problem at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: The example helped but the problem is the url that is getting generated. Look:  What I am getting is: `http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/js/fixtures.js?ver=1512129850` and not having the name of my plugin.. What I must get is: `http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/testingplugin/js/fixtures.js?ver=1512129850`

Comment: Are you using my bottom example. if so I've edited to include the , FILE in the plugins_url function.